# Create development profile using Enterprise account

Tags: ios, iphone, provisioning-profile

I know that we can create a development profile for debugging in device using a developer account(99$).  Whether we can create a development profile for debugging in device using a Enterprise account(299$). I had never used a enterprise account. I need a development profile for debugging in device using Enterprise account. I have to ask profile from my customer.

He shared a profile on my request but i was not able to debug in device using it. I checked the profile content. It had

```
        <key>get-task-allow</key>
    <false/>
```

I am sure that , if the key is false then it is distribution profile and not development profile. Please guide me?

Answer (score 0):

By "profile content" I am imagining you are talking about the Entitlements.plist file? You don't need one for a debug build, only for distribution builds. If you have a Entitlements file listed in the debug setting in the Code Signing Entitlements section in the build settings for your target, clear the entry.

Comment: Open the profile in text edit. The file has  <key>get-task-allow</key>
    <false/>. I don't use entitlement.plist

Comment: It sounds like he sent you an Ad Hoc profile. get-task-allow is set to true in a debug profile. An Enterprise account works the same as a developer account for debug builds. The difference is that, for an Enterprise account, you are not limited to the number of devices for your Ad Hoc builds (100 per year) and you can't use it to submit apps to the store.